# When i log transform pandas column i get NaNs should i replace these with 0?

Tags: pandas, normalization, logarithm

I cannot find a similar question. But i have a df with some columns highly skewed. I then plan to log transform these columns then standardize. However when i log transform i then get NaNs, should i replace these with 0;s?

```
log_train[skew_cols]=np.log2(featuresdf[skew_cols]
```

error i get is:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log2
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

not sure what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't replace with 0's, because np.log(1) is equal to 0. So then both 1, and 0 will be 0 in your log data.

Instead, just +1 your data prior to the log. Therefore log2(1) becomes 0, log2(2) (which was 1) is still 1, then log2(3) (which was 2) is now 1.58)

So the code would be:

```
log_train[skew_cols]=np.log2(featuresdf[skew_cols]+1)
```

The other option is to use other scaling methods that can handle 0, such as square root (np.sqrt)

Comment: many thanks. These columns were stil skewed after i log transformed them. The whole point of me wanting to log transform these columns is so that it is ready for logistic regression

Comment: No problem, keep in mind that for logistic regression, the error terms (residuals) do not need to be normally distributed (like how they do for linear). So this might not be required.

Comment: that saves me a world of pain, but dont they need to be scaled?

Comment: Depends on what you want to use the model for. Sometimes scaled metrics can become more difficult to interpret. Remember that odds rations are an 1 unit increase in x leads to the outcome being y times more likely. If your variables are scaled, the interpretability of the model can become more difficult. Also, if this answer did answer your question, it would be good to accept the answer.